# How to receive data on asp website from c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im sending data to local website using c# console application. Function that sends data is:

```
    public static HttpWebRequest GetRequest(String url, NameValueCollection nameValueCollection)
    {
        // Here we convert the nameValueCollection to POST data.
        // This will only work if nameValueCollection contains some items.
        var parameters = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string key in nameValueCollection.Keys)
        {
            parameters.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&",
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key),
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nameValueCollection[key]));
        }

        parameters.Length -= 1;

        // Here we create the request and write the POST data to it.
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(parameters.ToString());
        }

        return request;
    }
```

url and NameValueCollection are correct.
but I cant receive anything on the website.
website code is:

```
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);

    string requestFromPost = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Response.Write(requestFromPost);
```

I'm new to asp.net. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var parameters = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string key in nameValueCollection.Keys)
{
    parameters.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&",
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key),
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nameValueCollection[key]));
}

parameters.Length -= 1; 

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// Every so often I've seen weird issues if the user agent isn't set
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";

// encode the data for transmission
byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters.ToString());

// tell the other side how much data is coming
request.ContentLength = bytedata.Length; 

using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    writer.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
}
String result = String.Empty;

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
        result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // gets the response from the server
        // output this or at least look at it.
        // generally you want to send a success or failure message back.
    }
}

// not sure why you were returning the request object.
// you really just want to pass the result back from your method
return result;
```

You probably want to wrap most of the above in a `try..catch`.  If the post fails then it's going to throw an exception.

---

On the receiving end, it's a little easier.  You can do things like:

```
String val = Request.QueryString["myparam"];
```

or just iterate through the query string collection.

Comment: error: parameters doesn't exist in current context
error: cannot convert byte[] to char[]

Comment: @SparkWerk: I assumed you were still going to build your parameters...  updated

Comment: Im getting the idea. but how to convert byte[] to char[]error: cannot convert byte[] to char[] ?

Comment: Which line is throwing that?  I have nearly this exact same code in a production system.

Comment: writer.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);